# AWS RDS Postgres 11 database Connected to pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

**Question**

- What extra do I get if I fix this and get access to the admin database? (MyDataBaseName normal database works perfectly well)
- Do I even need to fix this to use this postgres database for a Django 3.0 project?

**Done -> ERROR**

1. I have created a free tear AWS RDS Postgres 11 database.
2. I allowed external connections at creation and have successfully configured the inbound rules.
3. Than I have connected to pgAdmin (right click on server groups/create/server)
4. Than I got 3 database:

   - `MyDataBaseName` how I have named my database
   - `postgesql` that is auto generated
   - `rdsadmin` this is also auto generated,

     - I have problem with this one that it doesn't opens,
     - it has a rex x at the database icon
     - if i click on it it gives the following ERROR message

```
INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
FATAL: SomeConfigFileName.conf rejects connection for host "host.ip.adders.actully.with.numbers", user "myPersonalUsername", database "rdsadmin", SSL on
FATAL: SomeConfigFileName.conf rejects connection for host "host.ip.adders.actully.with.numbers", user "myPersonalUsername", database "rdsadmin", SSL off
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to connect to "pgadmin" and getting an error saying that you can't connect to "rdsadmin"?  That would certainly be peculiar.  Please double  check your spellings.  Do you you have a connection pooler that might be translating your database names?

Comment: it is ```rdsadmin``` indeed I just renamed it in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"rdsadmin" is used for internal purposes by AWS. There should be no need to "fix" this.

The only things you are missing is things you aren't allowed to do anyway, and indeed not needing to deal with them yourself is what you are paying Amazon for.

Django shouldn't care.  If it demands access to this database, that would be a bug in Django (or a configuration error)